# How to get maxWidth and maxHeight parameters of ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, css

I have **ImageView** declared at xml:

```
...
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="60dip"
    android:maxWidth="60dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
 ...
```

And I want to get **maxWidth** and **maxHeight** paramater values programmatically:

```
...
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
int maxWidth = ?
int maxHeight = ?
...
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant member variables of the ImageView are `mMaxWidth` and `mMaxHeight`, both are declared private. There are also no getter methods available, which leaves you with one option:
Use reflection to inspect the fields.

Here is a sample how to do that:

```
int maxWidth = -1;
int maxHeight = -1;
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

try {
     Field maxWidthField = ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("mMaxWidth");
     Field maxHeightField = ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("mMaxHeight");
     maxWidthField.setAccessible(true);
     maxHeightField.setAccessible(true);

     maxWidth = (Integer) maxWidthField.get(iv);
     maxHeight = (Integer) maxHeightField.get(iv);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The other answers mention `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, but it's not the same. If you run the following snippet after the inspection above you will see differences *(given that the size and the max size are not identical at the moment due to the set values or the source image size)*:

```
Log.d("TEST", "width="+iv.getWidth()+" || height="+iv.getHeight());
Log.d("TEST", "maxWidth="+maxWidth+" || maxHeight="+maxHeight);
```

Comment: Yea, I thought there was a native way of **maxWidth** and **maxHeight** values extracting exists. But this way is still not founded. And I really forgot about reflection :) It works fine, thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Interesting thing: if maxWidth or maxHeight was not declared at XML 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE) would be got.

Comment: Yes, that's the default value. You can always [look into the source](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java&q=ImageView%20package:android&type=cs) if you are interested how the android internals work. E.g. you can directly see that there is no way of getting these max values since the variables are only used at a few points in the file when you search for their names.

Answer (score 1):

set width and height perimeters to fill parent in xml. then from code

```
imageview.getHeight();
```

and

```
imageview.getWidth();
```

will give you max available width/height of ImageView currently drawn on the screen.

Comment: Yea, but these values are not values of maxHeight and maxWidth parameters that I asked.